# Python, using glob with cwd argument to subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, glob

I want to call a subprocess in python using subprocess.call(), with the 'cwd' argument so that this particular subprocess is executed in a different directory. I don't want to use os.chdir() because for future processes later in the program I want to remain in the original directory from where the program was run.

BUT, I also want to run this particular subprocess on a set of files matching a glob pattern. So for example, I might want to do

```
subprocess.call(['ls'] + glob('*.txt'), cwd="/my/other/dir/")
```

But of course the glob command doesn't know to look in /my/other/dir, so it fails. How can I do this without using shell=True?

Comment: Are you trying to list all `.txt` files in `/my/other/dir/` ? If so, you do not need glob.

Comment: No, that was just an example. I'm trying to run a bespoke script processing all files with a .PHY extension in a subdir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the CWD in the glob pattern as well. Like `glob.glob("/my/other/dir/*.txt")`. It will expand with full match, like `/my/other/dir/aa.txt`. In case you do not want to pass the full path to the executable, cut it off.

```
CWD = "/my/other/dir/"
files = map(lambda x: x[len(CWD):], glob.glob(CWD + "*.txt"))
subprocess.call(['ls'] + files, cwd=CWD)
```

Or you could just change the directory back after the subprocess has finished.

Comment: In the absence of any other suggestions, using the full path is probably the way forward, although presumably this might cause problems with system independence. To avoid this I presume I could use a relative paths with os.getcwd() appended to CDW. It all seems a bit hacky, but I guess it should work, so I'll select this as the answer for the moment. I wish there were a cleaner way, though.

Comment: nothing in this solution requires absolute paths. There is no need to prepend `os.getcwd()`.